# Partial derivatives and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

How can I prove this:

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $a \in \Omega$. Let $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose that the partial derivatives of $f$ exist on $B(a, \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, and that there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$|D_j f(x)|<C \hspace{30pt} \mbox{for all }x \in B(a, \epsilon) \mbox{ and } j = 1, 2, \dots, n.$$
Prove that $f$ is continuous at a.

Thank you.

I have tried the following

By the given information, we have $\forall \epsilon' > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0, \epsilon > 0$ and $C > 0$ such that if $t < \delta$, then
$$\left|\frac{f(x + t e_j) - f(x) - D_j f(x)t}{t}\right| < \epsilon' \hspace{20pt} \forall x \in B(a, \epsilon), \mbox{ and } j = 1, 2, \dots, n$$
and
$$|D_jf(x)| < C \hspace{20pt} \forall x \in B(a, \epsilon).$$

My first approach is try to prove that $D_j f(x)$ is continuous at $a$. So I considered

\begin{align*}
|D_j f(x) - D_j f(a)| &= \frac{1}{|t|} | D_j f(x)t - D_j f(a)t |\\
&= \frac{1}{|t|} |D_j f(x)t - d(x) + d(a) - D_j f(a)t + d(x) - d(a)|,
\end{align*}
where $d(x) = f(x + te_j) - f(x)$. Hence
\begin{align*}
|D_j(x) - D_j f(a)| &\leq \frac{1}{|t|} \left[ |d(x) - D_j f(x)t| + |d(a) - D_jf(a)t| + |d(x) - d(a)| \right]\\
&< 2 \epsilon' + \frac{|d(x) - d(a)|}{|t|}
\end{align*}
and I am stuck here

Comment: I have tried to prove that the partial derivatives are continuous. But stucked

Comment: Continuity of $D_jf(x)$ is neither guaranteed by the conditions, nor is it in any way needful for this result. You are looking in the wrong direction. Review the proof for $g:\Bbb R\supset U  \to \Bbb R$ that the existance of $g'(x_0)$ implies continuity of $g$ at $x_0$. Can you see how to modify that for $n$ dimensions?

Comment: There is a trick you can use. If $h=(h_1, ..., h_n)$, define $v_k=h_1 e_1+...+h_k e_k$. Then $f(a+h)-f(a)=f(a+v_n)-f(a)=(f(a+v_n)-f(a+v_{n-1})) + (f(a+v_{n-1}) - f(a))=...$ and now you should what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$f(x)-f(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[f\left(a+\sum_{j=1}^i(x_j-a_j)\right)-f\left(a+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}(x_j-a_j)\right)\right]$$
where by convention $\sum_{j=1}^0(x_j-a_j):=0$. Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$f\left(a+\sum_{j=1}^i(x_j-a_j)\right)-f\left(a+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}(x_j-a_j)\right)=\int_{a_i}^{x_i}D_if(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},t,a_{i+1},\ldots,a_n)dt$$
which is bounded in absolute value by $C|x_i-a_i|$ if $x$ is close enough to $a$ (specifically, this holds for all $x\in R$, where $R\subset B(a,\epsilon)$ is an open rectangle containing $a$). Hence
$$|f(x)-f(a)|\le C\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a_i|\le C\sqrt{n}\|x-a\|$$
which completes the proof.